# How to define a list of all binary strings that match specific RegExp?

Tags: python, regex, binary

I have a regex that matches some binary strings. How to create a generator expression that defines a list of all strings that are accepted by this regex?

Please find the pseudocode.

```
pattern = re.compile("^(001|010|100){5}$") #accepts {001100001001001, 100100100001001,...} but not accepts {000000000000000,111111111111111,...}

def infinite_sequence():
    num = 000000000000000
    while True:
        yield num
        num += 1

good_binary_strings = [x for x in infinite_sequence() if re.match(pattern, x)]
```

I am interested in the most efficient code as possible. The real subset of strings is huge.

Comment: A naive approach: generate a list of binary strings and filter those which pass the test

Comment: how to write this simple code as efficient as possible

Comment: I think this (translated from pseudocode to actual code) is pretty optimal.. For general case, you have to test all options..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currently accepted answer by Jan Stránský generates 32767 different strings, which isn't too bad, but you can just straight up only generate the "good" strings, which is likely going to matter in your real dataset:

```
from itertools import product

good_binary_strings = [''.join(x) for x in product(['001', '010', '100'], repeat=5)]
print(len(good_binary_strings))
```

Answer (score 1):

your modified code (assuming all length=15 binary strings):

```py
import re
pattern = re.compile("^(001|010|100){5}$") #accepts {001100001001001, 100100100001001,...} but not accepts {000000000000000,111111111111111,...}

def infinite_sequence():
    num = 0
    while num <= 0b111111111111111:
        s = bin(num) # 0b10101
        s = s[2:] # 10101
        s = s.rjust(15,"0") # 000000000010101
        yield s
        num += 1

good_binary_strings = [x for x in infinite_sequence() if re.match(pattern, x)]
print(len(good_binary_strings))
```